# How do I properly pause in SpriteKit when the application goes to background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Ok, I know that SpriteKit automatically pauses and resumes games when the enter foregrounds and backgrounds, but I want to go to the pause menu (which is a method in my GameScene) whenever the application goes to the background. I do this by calling that method in `-applicationDidEnterBackground`, but for some reason the game crashes. What is the proper way to do this?

EDIT:

**This is the error message:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Attemped to add nil node', reason: 'Attemped to add nil node to parent: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181d2259c 0x1924780e4 0x181d224dc 0x18635812c 0x10003dd90 0x10003e818 0x1000394b0 0x1867627c0 0x18676acbc 0x18676ac44 0x18675e578 0x189f9162c 0x181cdaa28 0x181cd9b30 0x181cd7d30 0x181c050a4 0x18ada75a4 0x18653a3c0 0x10003f700 0x192ae6a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**This is what the pauseGame method does:**

```
NSLog(@"Pausing...");
[self removeActionForKey:@"spawn"];
[self addChild:self.pausedImage];
[self addChild:self.restart];
[self addChild:self.resume];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/menu.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]];
NSURL *pauseMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.pauseMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:pauseMusicURL error:nil];
self.pauseMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.pauseMusicPlayer play];

[self.pause removeFromParent];
self.scoreLabelInGame.position = CGPointMake(self.restart.position.x, self.resume.position.y - self.customUnit);
self.actualScore.position = CGPointMake(self.restart.position.x, self.scoreLabelInGame.position.y - self.customUnit);
self.isPaused = YES;
[self.mainMusicPlayer pause];
}
```

This basically stops every process in the game (Everything only works if isPaused = NO) And it simulates a pause menu on top of the game.

Comment: What's the crash message? What code are using to call your pause menu? Have you tried isolating possible issues?

Comment: did you check whether any of the nodes you are adding is nil? for e.g. `self.pausedImage` or `self.restart` or `self.resume`

Comment: Yeah that is it, I need them though. How could solve this, they need to be accessible from other methods, so they need to be properties, right?

Comment: I suggest you post the code that creates those nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that

1. you are populating **self.pausedImage**, **self.restart**, **self.resume**
2. at least 1 of the 3 properties above is erroneously **nil**

Now if my assumptions are correct (can you confirm?), I think one of the following scenarios can be the cause of the crash:

1. at least 1 of the 3 properties mentioned above are declared as **weak**
2. the code that **populates** these 3 properties has **never been called** when you pause the game
3. you have some code that **set to nil** at least 1 of the 3 properties

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were right, now the method gets called without crashing, however the pause menu is not opened upon entering the foreground

Comment: the properties were nil

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? **[self.pause removeFromParent];** I mean, why are you removing this node?

Comment: it is the pause button, i don't want it to show up in the menu

Comment: Ok, so the question is why **self.pausedImage** is now showing up? Maybe: **1)** it has wrong coordinates (it is placed outside the screen) **2)** it is hidden **3)** it does not contain an image **4)** It is covered by something with an higher zPosition. - Try to add self.pausedImage to the scene when the scene is loaded and verify it actually does contain something visible on the screen.